# Change the background clip after tracking - multiple clips loaded

Tags: rendering, image, tracking

I did some motion tracking on a clip and set the clip to be the background of the render. However I then loaded another clip to use instead, did the motion tracking, clicked 'Set as Background' and looking from the camera perspective in the 3D view I see this new clip as the background. However upon rendering, the background appears to be the old clip. How can I remove this old clip so I can see the new one instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you have as background image on the 3D view is just for viewing and work on the scene, but never gets rendered.

The background for rendering is set on diferent places depending on how you are rendering.

1. On the node editor:

[image]

2. If you're not using nodes:

[image]